# What new way to refresh a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the following method to refresh Fergmant

```
  Fragment frg = null;
  frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
  final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.detach(frg);
  ft.attach(frg);
  ft.commit();
```

Or

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

But after being updated

From

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

To

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

This methods no longer works. What method should I use to refresh the fragment now?

Comment: Which method is not used ?

Comment: Both methods do not work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try different usage for fragment refresh:

```
YourFragment f2 = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, f2);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the methods you have used are deprecated. You can try this way using the function `replace()` which replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.

```
Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```